# Action of a Dihedral Group on the Diagonals

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $n ⩾ 4$ be an even positive integer. Let us number the vertices of the $n$-gon by $\Bbb Z /n\Bbb Z$ (clockwise). And let $X=\{\{i,j\}$:$i$ and $j$ number opposite vertices}. So $X$ is the set of diagonals of the $n$-gon. Let $r ∈ D_{2n}$ be the rotation sending the vertex $0$ to the vertex $1$ and $s$ be the symmetry that fixes the vertex $0$.

- Let $σ ∈ D_{2n}$ and ${i, j} ∈ X$, show that ${σ(i), σ(j)} ∈ X$ where the action of $D_{2n}$ is the usual one.
- Show that $σ ⋆ {i, j} = {σ(i), σ(j)}$ is an action of $D_{2n}$ on $X$.
- Show that this action has a unique orbit.
- Show that $S_{D_{2n}}$$(\{i, j\})$ = $\{1, r^{n/2}, r^{2i}s, r^{2i+n/2}s\}$
- Let $n = 4$. Show that $S_{D_8}(X)$ = $\{1, r^2, s, r^2s\}$.
- Let $n > 4$. Show that $S_{D_{2n}}(X)$ = $\{1, r^{n/2}\}$.

---

I think I figured out the first two parts. I defined σ when $s^ar^b$ as $(-1)^a + b$ then proved that the vertices under the transformation are still paired by opposite by checking if $j = i + n/2$ mod $n$. Then to check if it was an action, I tested $r⋆(r⋆\{i,j\}) = (rr)\{i,j\}$, $r⋆(s⋆\{i,j\} = (rs)\{i,j\}$, and so on for sr and ss. (Is that correct?) Now I'm stuck on the third part. I'm kind of weak on the concept of orbits so I don't know what it means in this context. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!